# Struts vs. [j]Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, struts2, jruby, jrubyonrails

I've spent the last 9 months using Ruby on Rails exclusively.

I've been asked to join project and they are currently using Struts with Tomcat. I've done Java in the past and vowed never to go back for several reasons. They are currently having trouble finding people who know Java or are willing to join a project that uses it. (This is without pay but has potential)

I just don't think in the long run that I could tolerate Struts and if they need what Java as a platform offers like security and scaling, then they could migrate over to jRuby later on.

I'd like to hear what you guys think.

Comment: Write their project over the weekend in Rails and show it off on monday.

Comment: The reason they're having trouble finding people is because they're looking for people to work for free. There's tons of Java developers out there, but most of them code for a living.

Comment: Probably to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: True, startups are always difficult to find talent for free. My suggestion is going to be to re-write the project over 2 weeks and then switch over to jRuby if we ever are blessed enough to have scaling be a concern. Their reasons for choosing Java was security and scalability though neither of the two founders are coders, they are designers and engineers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree that Java (JRuby) offers security or scaling intrinsically. The performance is very close to C based interpreters. What you do get is the ability to use Java classes within your application. If the project has a need to use a specific Java library, or if the deployment stack must be Java, I'd definitely recommend JRuby (on Rails). Otherwise, expect similar results in a jRuby on Rails application as any other Ruby on Rails application.

Comment: You might want to ask Twitter about the scaling issues. ;)

Comment: True. Although the amount of scaling they are required to do is fairly complex compared to most applications. Furthermore, they have moved large parts of the application to Scala (running on a JVM) and still get regular issues (fail whale). Lots of resources exist to teach how Rails can scale (see http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails).

Answer (score -5):

Rails or Ruby are fine for small school projects,
look at Rail3 it has all the same staff taken from Struts2
Now the main point is how you work with JavaScript not server side programming,
and you lose all rails 'simplicity'.

Comment: Downvoted. Answer reflects sheer lack of knowledge and understanding of either struts or rails. Rails is definitely suitable for large scale projects and a lot of large scale projects are using for massive commercial solutions. Even when working with javascript heavy applications rails does not lose simplicity. In fact Rails controllers support multi-format responses and the Rails 3 restful controller actually help in creation of rich client applications which communicate with server via json. Rails asset pipeline is another plus which immensely aids client side development.